# CSS Grid First Item in Every Row (Select First Item of Each Row)

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-grid, css-transforms

I have a grid that is `auto-fill`ed using `grid-template-columns`. Is there a way to select every **first** element of every row even though the grid is `auto-fill`ed.  That is say, I have the following CSS:

```css
grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 185px);
  grid-auto-rows: 280px;
}

grid > div {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  width: 250px;
}

grid > div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  width: 250px;
}
```

This produces the following grid:

```
 ____   ____   ____   ____         ____
|    | |    | |    | |    |       |    |
| A1 | |    | |    | |    |  ...  |    |
|____| |____| |____| |____|       |____|
                  ...
 ____   ____   ____   ____         ____
|    | |    | |    | |    |       |    |
| An | |    | |    | |    |  ...  |    |
|____| |____| |____| |____|       |____|
```

I would like to select all `A1` - `An` grid elements to add additional CSS rules.

**Additional Information:**
Each grid item has a `:hover` event where it scales to 1.2.  When it does, the left most item of each row is displayed outside the window.  That is, it creates a horizontal scrollbar and it is not possible to see the entire content.  Therefore, I can use the `transform-origin` to reposition.  But I need to apply this CSS rule to only the first element of each row.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: No there is not. At least with CSS

Comment: except if you have a specific class for every first element, in css I think you can't

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child()` selector gives us access to every element that’s first in its row, as long as we know the number of columns. For example,

`:nth-child(3n + 1) { }` when there is 3 column in your grid.
`:nth-child(4n + 1) { }` for 4 column.

Inside the :nth-child() function, 3n finds every element whose position is divisible by 3 (0, 3, 6, 9 so on).

And if you want access last element of each row then use `:nth-child(3n + 3) when there is 3 column in your grid.

So, the simple equation is,

`:nth-child({number_of_column}n + 1)` for first element of each row.

`:nth-child({number_of_column}n + {number_of_column})` for last element of each row.